# Extjs4, I changed AbsoultePanel's Item's X position, but They can not Change position

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I'm Student with EXTJS4..

I added Ext.Img to AbsolutePanel, and I set the Position.

And after, I Changed Ext.Img's Position, Like this.

```
img.x = 30;
```

But He no Change his Position.

What can i do for this Problem?

This is my Code..

Ext.Img..

```
var paddleItem1 = {
xtype : 'image',
src : "lib/Image/Paddle.png",
x : 0,
y : 0,
draggable : true,
index : 0,
id : 'paddleItem1',
dx : 2,
dy : 2,
name: 'rightPaddle',
type: 'Paddle',
color : '255,0,0',
w : 100,
h : 100,
hid : 'paddleItem1'
```

};

And this is AbsolutePanel.

```
var centerRegion = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        title : 'Center Region',
        region : 'center',
        layout : 'absolute',
        margins : '5 5 0 5',
        id : 'designSpace'
    });
```

And this is Add Item to AbsolutePanel.

```
centerRegion.add(paddleItem);
```

Last, This is Change Position Code

```
centerRegion.items.items[0].x = 30;
```

Comment: Sorry I find Answer. Just use .setPosition() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the setPosition method:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    var vp = Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
        layout: 'absolute',
        items: {
            title: 'Foo',
            x: 10,
            y: 10,
            width: 100,
            height: 100
        }
    });

    setTimeout(function() {
        vp.items.first().setPosition(30, 30);
    }, 1000);
});
```